# Cannot navigate to my webpage without "www." what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web, deployment, web-hosting

I made my first deployment with RoR, Heroku and GoDaddy hosting. I am able to navigate with "www.mypage.com" but I cant just go to "mypage.com". The page doesn't even load and there is no error message. Did I make a mistake in my deployment or is it something with the connection of GoDaddy and Heroku?

Comment: You need to set up a redirect from mypage.com to http:www.mypage.com.

Comment: @ruby_newbie is that something that happens in GoDaddy or Heroku? There is a domain name and dns target in Heroku, I would assume it happens there?

Comment: Pretty sure it is done on Godaddy but you can also do it at the server level.